# Session Variables Are Empty After JQuery Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, redirect

1. I have a form that is validated using JQuery then submitted to self
   (Page A) using JQuery as will. The submission is detected by a PHP
   script. (This works perfectly)
2. After submission the JQuery script redirect to another page (Page
   B).
3. The other page uses a value that is stored in a session variable in
   the previous page to retrieve data from the DB.

Everything is fine the issue is that the session variable is empty when redirected! i tried all kind of different stuff but no use. Im not sure what am i doing wrong that is causing the session to be emptied. I'm suspecting that the issue is with the JQuery that redirects to page B.

Page A JQuery and Session Code

```
    <?php
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['fs'])){

    $randval =  substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['rref'] = $randval;
    //some other code that works fine
    }}
    ?>

    <form method="REQUEST" id="form" name="form" class="aj">
      //some fields and codes
      <input type="hidden" name="fs" value="fs" id="fs" >
      <input type="submit" value="Reserve" id="btn-form-valid" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;" onclick="jQuery('.aj').parsley('validate');">
    </form>

    <script>
      jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('.aj').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if ( jQuery(this).parsley().isValid() ) {
            jQuery.ajax({
              type: "post",
              data: jQuery(".aj").serialize(),
              success: function (data) {
                window.location.assign("http://location");
              }
              ,
              beforeSend: function() {
              }
            }
           });
          });
    </script>
```

Page B code

```
    <?php
session_start();
    $x = $_SESSION['rref'];
    echo $x;
//nothing is returned
?>
```

I tried searching for people who had similar problems but nothing was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to place session_start at the beginning:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['fs'])){

        $randval =  substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);

        $_SESSION['rref'] = $randval;
        //some other code that works fine
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I did, in both pages, with no use.

Comment: Try with var_dump(session_start()) to see if returns true

Comment: it returned bool(true)